# MQMessage deos not send whole message

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

I am fairly new to MQMessage broker. In my project, I want to send an xml message. Every thing is ok but when message get larger than 500 bytes, My code send broken message to the Queue. what I am doing is

```
//queueManager has been initialized in the class constructor and connected to a channel.
        public MQResponse WriteMsg(string QueueName, string strInputMsg)
        {
            MQResponse response = new MQResponse();
            try
            {
                queue = queueManager.AccessQueue(QueueName,
                    MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING );

                queueMessage = new MQMessage();
                queueMessage.DataOffset = 0;
                //queueMessage.MessageLength = 2000000;
                queueMessage.ResizeBuffer(6 * strInputMsg.Length);
                queueMessage.WriteString(strInputMsg);
                queueMessage.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;

                queuePutMessageOptions = new MQPutMessageOptions();
                queue.Put(queueMessage, queuePutMessageOptions);
                response.Message = "Message sent to the queue successfully";
                response.Status=MQResponseStatus.WriteSuccessful;
            }
            catch (MQException MQexp)
            {
                response.Message = "Exception: " + MQexp.Message;
                response.Status=MQResponseStatus.WriteFail;
                response.CatchedException=MQexp;
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                response.Message = "Exception: " + exp.Message;
                response.Status=MQResponseStatus.WriteFail;
                response.CatchedException=exp;
            }
            return response;
        }
```

I guess queueMessage should be initialized correctly so that we able to send whole message.

Comment: I would add two things to Shashi's response.  1) If you get a JMS exception, print the linked exception. JMS exceptions are a multi-level data structure where the linked exception has the vendor-specific errors. If the app doesn't print it, then it can be very difficult to debug. 2) You mentioned using a client channel but I don't see any `COMMIT` called.  When using async messaging over a network, *always* use transacted sessions and the `COMMIT` method. See the JMS 1.1 spec *4.4.13 Duplicate Production of Messages* or my other SO answers for an explanation of why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all how did you determine that the message is broken? Did you try to receive the sent message and compared with the original message or you viewed the message using MQExplorer or some other means. MQExplorer by default displays first 1000 bytes of the message. To view more you need to change the `Max data bytes displayed` setting in `Window/Preferences/Messages` panel.

WebSphere MQ can handle messages of size as large as 100 MB.

Regarding your code snippet above: The few lines of code is enough to build and send a message.

```
            queueMessage = new MQMessage();
            queueMessage.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING; 
            queueMessage.WriteString(strInputMsg);
            queuePutMessageOptions = new MQPutMessageOptions();
            queue.Put(queueMessage, queuePutMessageOptions);
```

Comment: I Looked in the queue using MQ Explorer and I realized that My message is broken. every time I send a large message, I got a broken one in the queue. I know that each message can be up to 100 MB but I dont have any idea.

Comment: As I said MQExplorer will show only the first 1000 bytes. Did you change the Message Preferences and try?